# player will sometimes phase through platforms in prototype of infinite runner game?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, game-physics

I'm coding an infinite runner game in javascript using the html5 canvas, and it's been going pretty well so far, but I have been getting the jump mechanism in place, and sometimes the player will phase through the platform they land on, which they shouldn't do, as i have code in place to prevent that. By the way, while the player will not be able to phase through the sides of the platforms in the finished game, I have no code in place to prevent it yet. This only happens on the platform one object. Any idea why it is doing this? My code is here-

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('gameframe')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
var player = {
  y: 250,
  x: 250,
  w: 30,
  h: 30
}

var plat1 = {
  x: 250,
  y: 350,
  w: 250,
  h: 300
}
var plat2 = {
  x: 50,
  y: 400,
  w: 250,
  h: 300
}
var plat3 = {
  x: -200,
  y: 375,
  w: 250,
  h: 300
}
var currentPlat = {
  x: 1,
  y: 1,
  w: 1,
  h: 1
}

function renderPlatforms() {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.rect(plat1.x, plat1.y, plat1.w, plat1.h);
  ctx.rect(plat2.x, plat2.y, plat2.w, plat2.h);
  ctx.rect(plat3.x, plat3.y, plat3.w, plat3.h);
  ctx.fill();
  plat1.x--;
  plat2.x--;
  plat3.x--;
  if (plat1.x === 0 - plat1.w) {
    plat1.x = 500;
  }
  if (plat2.x === 0 - plat2.w) {
    plat2.x = 500;
  }
  if (plat3.x === 0 - plat3.w) {
    plat3.x = 500;
  }

}

function renderPlayer() {
  ctx.rect(player.x, player.y, player.w, player.h)
  ctx.fill();
}

function draw() {
  getCurrentPlat();
  doGravity();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  renderPlayer();
  renderPlatforms();
  ctx.fill();
  setTimeout(draw, 3)


}
draw();

function getCurrentPlat() {
  if (player.x + player.w >= plat1.x && player.x <= plat1.x + plat1.w) {
    currentPlat.x = plat1.x;
    currentPlat.y = plat1.y;
    currentPlat.w = plat1.w;
    currentPlat.h = plat1.h;
    console.log('on platform one')
    console.log()
  }
  if (player.x + player.w >= plat2.x && player.x <= plat2.x + plat2.w) {

    currentPlat.x = plat2.x;
    currentPlat.y = plat2.y;
    currentPlat.w = plat2.w;
    currentPlat.h = plat2.h;
  }
  if (player.x + player.w >= plat3.x && player.x <= plat3.x + plat3.w) {

    currentPlat.x = plat3.x;
    currentPlat.y = plat3.y;
    currentPlat.w = plat3.w;
    currentPlat.h = plat3.h;
  }
}


function doGravity() {
  if (player.y + 30 < currentPlat.y && jumping === false) {
    player.y++;
  }
}
var cntr = 0
var jumping = false

function jump() {
  jumping = true;
  if (cntr < 90) {
    cntr++;
    player.y--;
    setTimeout(jump, 2);
  } else {
    function fls() {
      jumping = false;
    }
    cntr = 0;
    setTimeout(fls, 50)

  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<canvas width='500' height='500' id='gameframe' style='border-style: solid;'>Sorry, canvas is not supported for your browser. </canvas>
<button onclick='jump()'>jump</button>
<script src='script.js'></script>

</html>
```

Comment: There's a _"Tidy"_ button in the snippet editor. Please use it.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? If this only happens on "platform 1" then why are there 3 other platforms? Is this really a [mcve]?

Comment: not sure. I see no reason for it to happen, so I am really just looking to see if anyone knows how it's happening, not how to fix it, and having the other platforms as a control group could be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it was intentional but your platforms do overlap...
see it in the sample below

I did improve your code to use an array for the platforms instead of individual items, then we can loop `platforms.forEach` that should help you reduce the duplicate code, and adding many more platforms in the future will be very easy.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('gameframe')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

var platforms = [
  {x: 250,  y: 50,  w: 250,h: 301},
  {x: 50,   y: 100, w: 250,h: 302},
  {x: -200, y: 75,  w: 250,h: 303}
]

function renderPlatforms() {  
  platforms.forEach(function(p) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(p.x, p.y, p.w, p.h);
    ctx.fillText(p.x, p.x +5, p.y-5);
    ctx.fillText(p.w + " / " +p.h, p.x +5, p.y+20);
    ctx.stroke();      
    if (p.x-- === 0 - p.w) p.x = canvas.width;      
  })  
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  renderPlatforms();
  setTimeout(draw, 10)
}
draw();
```

```html
<canvas width='500' height='150' id='gameframe' style='border-style: solid;'></canvas>
```

If you are going to overlap the platforms like that you have to change your logic and check if the player collides with any of the platforms your approach to only check against one (a current platform) is creating problems.

When troubleshooting games I find `ctx.fillText()` more helpful than the `console.log()` you can show on screen the values of the objects also quite often slowing down the game helps you see if the values really change when you expect them too change.